# High load but low cpu usage

Tags: performance, top

`top` shows extreme high load, but cpu usage is relatively low. High load is consequence of many (~30) processes, started with niceness level of 15, so system is responsive.

```
top - 18:51:04 up 28 days, 16:30,  5 users,  load average: 254.30, 267.54, 265.42
Tasks: 421 total,  15 running, 406 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.4 us,  7.6 sy, 76.7 ni,  1.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  98940592 total, 98165984 used,   774616 free,  1577264 buffers
KiB Swap: 10059673+total,   659128 used, 99937600 free. 56868984 cached Mem

PID   USER  PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                              
49138 root  20   0  0.226t 0.025t 0.012t S 152.4 26.9   9192:51 java                                                                                 
15617 root  35  15 3821500 2.122g  16820 R  96.5  2.2 476:47.21 run_proc                                                                             
30440 root  35  15 5654432 200788  22960 S  82.6  0.2  18:49.65 run_proc                                                                  
37970 root  35  15 4706700 173912  18268 R  82.0  0.2   2241:08 run_proc                                                                  
45289 root  35  15 3723844 187600   8880 R  80.3  0.2   2142:22 run_proc                                                                  
11930 root  35  15  986632 150748  15836 R  52.2  0.2  31:06.74 run_proc                                                                         
 9921 root  35  15 2020804 105872   4812 S  24.8  0.1   2369:07 app                                                                              
30500 root  35  15 1455168 109312   7172 S  21.8  0.1 619:19.67 app                                                                              
 9963 root  35  15 3011908 144264  16804 S  21.2  0.1 282:59.01 run_proc                                                                  
24406 root  35  15 1989336  41164   3800 S  18.5  0.0 447:19.64 app                                                                              
46617 root  35  15 4159848 144072  17428 S  17.5  0.1 277:42.93 run_proc                                                                  
11280 root  35  15 4160060 148816  17484 S  16.9  0.2 283:00.52 run_proc                                                                  
24409 root  35  15 4889308 154020  17816 S  15.9  0.2 295:25.44 run_proc                                                                  
45562 root  35  15 3011940 148496  16860 S  15.9  0.2 286:21.70 run_proc                                                                  
22428 root  35  15 4422012 144080  17440 S  14.5  0.1 280:29.95 run_proc                                                                  
41371 root  35  15 1532440 206976  14208 S  13.6  0.2 291:10.54 app                                                                              
44285 root  35  15 5157436 162172  17904 R  13.6  0.2 298:19.36 run_proc                                                                  
 3793 root  35  15 4421984 150392  17432 S  12.6  0.2 293:43.98 run_proc                                                                  
41325 root  35  15 4553164 149596  17460 S  12.6  0.2 292:41.16 run_proc                                                                  
 2571 root  35  15 3011924 144388  16804 S  12.2  0.1 286:04.91 run_proc                                                                  
 4707 root  35  15 3011924 142384  16832 S  12.2  0.1 283:09.38 run_proc                                                                  
33573 root  35  15 4159992 144296  17432 R  12.2  0.1 282:51.66 run_proc                                                                  
42805 root  35  15 3011900 146272  16800 S  12.2  0.1 275:29.13 run_proc                                                                  
47365 root  35  15 4889804 154008  17740 R  12.2  0.2 286:58.69 run_proc                                                                  
33670 root  35  15 4159452 147980  17464 S  10.9  0.1 284:35.61 run_proc                                                                  
 1316 root  35  15 2100388 187292  12700 S  10.6  0.2 403:51.63 app                                                                              
35410 root  35  15 4295312 153696  18072 R  10.6  0.2 288:10.70 run_proc                                                                  
39749 root  35  15 4356064 152000  17436 R  10.6  0.2 284:17.87 run_proc                                                                  
12727 root  35  15 3011940 150384  16832 S   9.6  0.2 276:58.67 run_proc                                                                  
  484 root  35  15 4421584 149924  17432 S   9.3  0.2 275:11.69 run_proc                                                                  
10099 root  35  15 5085108 158916  17784 S   9.3  0.2 296:36.48 run_proc                                                                  
17062 root  35  15 4356448 144248  17432 S   8.9  0.1 281:26.88 run_proc                                                                  
20880 root  35  15 4291720 144784  17432 S   8.6  0.1 282:45.64 run_proc
```

```

What I don't really understand is why is cpu usage so low? I mean, if there are so many processes in run queue, why cpus are not execute them instead of being idle? What I expect here is cpu usage of 1200%  (system has 12 cpu cores). As you can notice, there is no heavy I/O utilization here.

```
root@~# iostat -d -x
Linux 3.13.0-119-generic (server)   11/20/17    _x86_64_    (12 CPU)

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.16    40.12   28.82   75.55  1176.18  2775.77    75.73     0.49    4.72    5.41    4.46   0.38   3.97
```

It's also worth mentioning that each of those `run_proc` processes creates ~30 threads, most of them in `S` state:

```
root@d:~# top -H -p 46660

  PID USER  PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
48563 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  3.7  0.1 339:33.64 run_proc
48309 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.7  0.1   1:35.97 run_proc
48281 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.3  0.1   1:35.50 run_proc
48294 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.3  0.1   1:35.70 run_proc
46660 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   0:40.41 run_proc
46959 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
46960 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
46961 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
46962 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
46963 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
46964 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
46965 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
46966 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
47717 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
48254 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   1:36.84 run_proc
48270 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   1:35.32 run_proc
48271 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   1:35.54 run_proc
48272 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   1:38.97 run_proc
48278 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   1:35.45 run_proc
48279 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   1:36.43 run_proc
48286 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   1:37.92 run_proc
48296 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   1:37.09 run_proc
48297 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   1:35.84 run_proc
48298 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   1:38.47 run_proc
48312 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   1:37.07 run_proc
48317 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 R  0.0  0.1   1:36.06 run_proc
48323 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   1:37.90 run_proc
48360 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
48362 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:09.49 run_proc
48445 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:40.89 run_proc
48447 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
48448 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 run_proc
48559 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:22.75 run_proc
48560 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.26 run_proc
48561 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:22.78 run_proc
48562 root  35  15 3011912 138636  13156 S  0.0  0.1   0:23.02 run_proc
```

Comment: Please tell us what `run_proc` does. If it is just performing a `sleep 5000`, for example, CPU load will be low, so will I/O. It all depends on what those processes are doing ...

Comment: @thecarpy, if processes does `sleep 5000`, most of the time would be in interuptable sleep (`S`), which basically is the case, as it can be seen, but I wonder how is possible that load is 250

Comment: looks I did not calculate `ni` at cpu usage! So basically, everything is fine here. `ni` is 77, so overall cpu usage is almost 100%. Also `id` of 1% tells everything.

Comment: Running jvm as root? It is possible, but highly uncommon. I think you should probably take more care about security.

Comment: What does `iostat -d -x` show?

Comment: @roaima, it's not duplicate, there is no high I/O here.

Comment: @peterh, it's actually not run as root, I edited output before pasting here, so I used `root` user for every process.

Comment: Duplicate suggestion withdrawn. Thank you for the additional information you've added to your question. I hope you get a useful answer.

Comment: @roaima, It's my bad, I oversaw `ni` in `top` output. I just wait for someone to give nicely formated answer, and to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [noted in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405636/high-load-but-low-cpu-usage#comment725635_405636), in *this particular case* the catch was: the CPU utilization is reported as several numbers - `14.4 us,  7.6 sy, 76.7 ni`. Quoting from ["What does 'nice' mean on CPU utilization graphs?"](https://serverfault.com/q/116950/58957) -

- %user: Percentage of CPU utilization that occurred while executing at the user level (application).
- %nice: Percentage of CPU utilization that occurred while executing at the user level with nice priority.
- %system: Percentage of CPU utilization that occurred while executing at the system level (kernel).

The "nice priority" usage, which was high in this particular case, indicates "the % of CPU time occupied by user level processes with a positive nice value (lower scheduling priority -- see [`man nice`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nice.1.html) for details)".

---

If you encounter high load with low *total CPU utilization*, remember that "load average" on Linux includes any tasks in the uninterruptible state (there are many reasons for a task to be in that state, such as waiting for I/O) - see [this serverfault Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/667078/58957) for a few short explanations or, if you want to take a deep dive, read through ["Linux Load Averages: Solving the Mystery" by Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html).

Also relevant: [High Load Average with modest CPU Utilization and almost no IO](https://serverfault.com/q/482832/58957) on serverfault.